# launchd: bash command doesn't run

Tags: macos, bash, launchd

I'm still a bit shaken after realising OS X doesn't offer straightforward solution to schedule tasks. Maybe that's the reason why I'm not able to find the reason behind my launchd plist issues. I thought that's gonna be an easy task and after a bit of reading I came with:

```
Frost:~ ren$ cat /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.mvps.hosts.plist 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>org.mvps.hosts</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>bash</string>
        <string>-c</string>
        <string>curl -s http://winhelp2002.mvps.org/hosts.txt | grep \"^0\.0\.0\.0\|^127\.0\.0\.1\|^::1\" &gt; /etc/hosts</string>
    </array>
    <key>StartInterval</key>
    <integer>86400</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

but for everything in the world I can't figure why after loading and starting /etc/hosts doesn't update. The command itself works so the issue is probably in formatting or escaping..? I didn't find any way to get any other lead than launchctl list status 127 for the job, whatever it points to. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe try `sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.mvps.hosts.plist` if you haven't already.

Comment: plist has never been disabled.

Comment: No, it shouldn't. > is XML reserved character.

Comment: Did you run the command fully with the sub-shell? I just tried `sudo bash -c "curl -s http://winhelp2002.mvps.org/hosts.txt | grep \"^0\.0\.0\.0\|^127\.0\.0\.1\|^::1\" >> /etc/hosts"` i.e. I put the actual command in quotes as well, and it worked.

Comment: Didn't help either, I didn't mention I tried as one of first experiments. The answer is to run bash and pass another bash with command into it. Don't know why but at least it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I end up with:

```
Frost:~ ren$ cat /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.mvps.hosts.plist 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>org.mvps.hosts</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>bash</string>
        <string>-c</string>
        <string>bash -c "curl -s http://winhelp2002.mvps.org/hosts.txt | grep \"^0\.0\.0\.0\|^127\.0\.0\.1\|^::1\" &gt; /etc/hosts"</string>
    </array>
    <key>StartInterval</key>
    <integer>86400</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Frankly, I have no idea why I have to call bash to call bash to run command, it's something with inner workings on launchd which I don't like anyway. It works now.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried absolute path for bash and/or curl and/or grep?
i.e. /bin/bash /usr/bin/curl or wherever they stay on your fs?